# a4j:repeat tag is not working

Tags: jsf, ajax4jsf

```
<a4j:form id="customerForm1" binding="#{customerForm.form}"
          ajaxSubmit="false">

    <h:inputHidden id="id" value="#{customerForm.customer.id}" />

    <rich:panel id="purchaseOrderList"
                styleClass="dataTablePanelStyle">
        <a4j:outputPanel id="table">
            <table border="1" width="100%">
                <thead>
                    <tr align="center">

                        <th width="8%"><h:outputText id="headerq"
                                      value="#{msg.distance}" styleClass="boldOutputTextStyle" /></th>
                        <th width="2%"><h:outputText id="ds8" value="" /></th>

                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <a4j:repeat
                        value="#{customerForm.customer.distanceTravelledList}"
                        var="purchaseOrderDetails" rowClasses="row1, row2">
                        <tr class="#{(rowIndex mod 2 eq 0)? 'row1' : 'row2'}">
                            <td align="center" width="10%">
                                <h:inputText id="distance" size="5" required="true"
                                             value="#{purchaseOrderDetails.distance}"
                                             styleClass="inputTextStyle">

                                </h:inputText>
                            </td>
                            <td><a4j:commandButton value="+"
                                               action="#{customerForm.addDistanceTravelled}"
                                               reRender="purchaseOrderList">
                                </a4j:commandButton></td>

                        </tr>
                    </a4j:repeat>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </a4j:outputPanel>
    </rich:panel>
</a4j:form>
```

I have created a table where I have used a4j:repeat tag, so that the user can dynamically add the rows depending on his requirement..But when I remove this tag ie a4j:repeat frontend displays only one row ie both column name and input text field.. But when I add  a4j:repeat` only the colum names are displayed ie Distance...Can any one tel Me what have I missed ??

Comment: You can use rich:dataTable for this instead of a4j:repeat

Comment: @newuser thank you for your suggestion.. But is der any way to make dis code work ??..

Comment: I already use the same type but it works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I am using such a table for my process. It works fine for me it may help for you.

```
<table border="1" width="100%">
<thead>
    <tr align="center">

        <th width="8%"><h:outputText id="headerq"
                      value="#{msg.distance}" styleClass="boldOutputTextStyle" /></th>
        <th width="2%"><h:outputText id="ds8" value="" /></th>

    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <a4j:repeat
        value="#{customerForm.customer.distanceTravelledList}"
        var="purchaseOrderDetails" rowKeyVar="rowIndex">
        <tr>
            <td align="center" width="10%">
                <h:inputText id="distance" required="true"
                             value="#{purchaseOrderDetails.distance}"
                             styleClass="inputTextStyle">
                </h:inputText>
            </td>
            <td><a4j:commandButton value="+"
                               action="#{customerForm.addDistanceTravelled}"
                               reRender="purchaseOrderList">
                </a4j:commandButton></td>
        </tr>
    </a4j:repeat>
</tbody>
```

Comment: You just remove the rowClass and then run it. I tried your source and it works fine for me. I updated the working source.

Comment: thanks a lot for  your time.. But even after pasting ur code..result is stil da same.. Do u think its because of  any version problem..?? I am displaying this table inside a popup.. ie rich:modalPanel..